# How to calculate the percentage of each value in a column follow each category in python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having a dataframe and trying to get  the output which shows percentage of each value in different category. Can anyone help on how can I do it?

Raw data table:

| Interface_Bin | Product |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ADL |
| 1 | ADL |
| 22 | ADL |
| 97 | ADL |
| 1 | JSL |
| 1 | JSL |
| 97 | JSL |
| 97 | JSL |
| 22 | JSL |

Expected outcome:

| Product | Bin(97)_count | Total_interfacebin_count | Bin_97_percentage_vs total count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ADL | 1 | 4 | 25% |
| JSL | 2 | 5 | 40% |

Thanks alot.

Comment: Can you add real data from sample to `Expected outcome:` ? Also your code, what you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.crosstab(df['Product'], df['Interface_Bin'])

f1 = lambda x: f'Bin({x})_count'
f2 = lambda x: f'Bin({x})_percentage_vs total count'
s = df.sum(axis=1).rename('Total_interfacebin_count')

df2 = df.div(s, axis=0).rename(columns=f2).mul(100)
df = pd.concat([df.rename(columns=f1), s, df2], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
         Bin(1)_count  Bin(1)_percentage_vs total count  Bin(22)_count  \
Product                                                                  
ADL                 2                              50.0              1   
JSL                 2                              40.0              1   

         Bin(22)_percentage_vs total count  Bin(97)_count  \
Product                                                     
ADL                                   25.0              1   
JSL                                   20.0              2   

         Bin(97)_percentage_vs total count  Total_interfacebin_count  
Product                                                               
ADL                                   25.0                         4  
JSL                                   40.0                         5
```

Answer (score 0):

first sort the data so you get a dictionary (or list) like:
{"ADL":121,"JSL":218}
probably with code like

```
for element in table row:
  if dict.contains(element.key) //in this case ADL or JSL
    dict[element.key].value+=element.value
  else
    dict[element.key]=element.value
```

then go through and sum all the dictionary values to get the total sum, or sum them as you add to the dictionary in the above code
finally get each percentage as (dict[key].value/sum)*100 + "%"